# Zipping files using Powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

I have a script below to zip what's in folder.txt. But what I want is to zip including the folders one by one and put on the same location.

```
$Src = "C:\Users\Asus\Documents\PowerShell\Folder.txt"
Compress-Archive –Path (Get-Content $Src) -DestinationPath C:\Users\Asus\Documents\PowerShell
```

let's say:

content in folder.txt:

New Folder

New Folder 2

what will happen is i will have New folder.zip and New Folder 2.zip in same location `(C:\Users\Asus\Documents\PowerShell)`

Can anyone help me on this? i have a lot of folders that need to be zipped but need to be specified.

If also possible to put password (same password for all, like 'abcd') as i am using SecureZip.

Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what SecureZip is (never heard of it until your post), but If you are already using a 3rdP Zip tool why are you using the cmdlet at all? The cmdlet does not offer a way to apply passwords, so you need to use a 3rdP zip tool like 7Zip, DotNetZip, etc. You then just use Get-ChildItem cmdlet in a loop to get your directories and pass them to your zip tool using the tools command switches to protect the zip. There are plenty of examples of this all over the web.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment. Choose a resource, review and tweak as needed.

['powershell 7ip folders with password'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%207ip%20folders%20with%20password%27&t=hk&ia=web)

Example hit(s)

[PowerShell function to create a password protected zip file](https://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-function-to-create-a-password-protected-zip-file)
[Download the function script](https://blog.danskingdom.com/assets/Posts/2013/09/Write-ZipUsing7Zip.zip)

```
function Write-ZipUsing7Zip
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$FilesToZip, 
        [string]$ZipOutputFilePath, 
        [string]$Password, 
        [ValidateSet('7z','zip','gzip','bzip2','tar','iso','udf')]
        [string]$CompressionType = 'zip', 
        [switch]$HideWindow
    )
    # Look for the 7zip executable.
    $pathTo32Bit7Zip = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    $pathTo64Bit7Zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

    $THIS_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $pathToStandAloneExe = Join-Path $THIS_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY "7za.exe"

    if (Test-Path $pathTo64Bit7Zip) { $pathTo7ZipExe = $pathTo64Bit7Zip }
    elseif (Test-Path $pathTo32Bit7Zip) { $pathTo7ZipExe = $pathTo32Bit7Zip }
    elseif (Test-Path $pathToStandAloneExe) { $pathTo7ZipExe = $pathToStandAloneExe }
    else { throw "Could not find the 7-zip executable." }

    # Delete the destination zip file if it already exists (i.e. overwrite it).
    if (Test-Path $ZipOutputFilePath) 
    { Remove-Item $ZipOutputFilePath -Force }

    $windowStyle = "Normal"
    if ($HideWindow) { $windowStyle = "Hidden" }

    # Create the arguments to use to zip up the files.
    # Command-line argument syntax can be found at: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples
    $arguments = "a -t$CompressionType ""$ZipOutputFilePath"" ""$FilesToZip"" -mx9"
    if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password))) 
    { $arguments += " -p$Password" }

    # Zip up the files.
    $p = Start-Process $pathTo7ZipExe -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -PassThru -WindowStyle $windowStyle

    # If the files were not zipped successfully.
    if (!(($p.HasExited -eq $true) -and ($p.ExitCode -eq 0)))
    {
        throw "There was a problem creating the zip file '$ZipFilePath'."
    }
}
```

BTW, there are PowerShell add-on modules in the Microsoft powershellgallery.com for 7Zip.

```
Find-Module -Name '*zip*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results
<#
Version Name            Repository Description                                                                                                                        
------- ----            ---------- -----------                                                                                                                        
1.13.0  7Zip4Powershell PSGallery  Powershell module for creating and extracting 7-Zip archives                                                                       
0.3.1   Zip             PSGallery  PowerShell module for creating ZIP archives.                                                                                       
2.2.0   PS7Zip          PSGallery  Powershell module that allows you to work with compressed archives                                                                 
1.0.8   x7Zip           PSGallery  Powershell DSC Configuration Script for installing 7-Zip versions 15.07, 15.06, 15.05, 9.38, and 9.20. This Configuration Script...
1.3.4   7ZipArchiveDsc  PSGallery  PowerShell DSC Resource to expand an archive file to a specific path.                                                              
0.2.2   ziphelper       PSGallery  Tools to work with zip archives                                                                                                    
1.1.0   7zip-Archive    PSGallery  7zip utility wrapper....                                                                                                           
0.1.1   Get-GzipContent PSGallery  Gets the content of the gzip archive at the specified location.  
#>
```

See this article on it.

https://www.sans.org/blog/powershell-7-zip-module-versus-compress-archive-with-encryption

Comment: Thank you! i'll explore this. Try if this will work on SecureZip

Comment: No worries. If it does resolve you use case, be sure to mark it as your accepted answer. If not come back and let us know what happened.